# makecontext function pointer [error: invalid use of void expression]

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have the following code (its for an threads library to a class):

```
int tcb_context_create(TCB *thread, void (*start)(void*), void *arg) {
    if (!makecontext( &(thread->context), (void (*) (void)) start, 1, arg)) {
        errno = EAGAIN;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But i the compiler keep giving 'error: invalid use of void expression' i have searched everywhere and cant find the corrent way to use the makecontext function.

corrected:

```
int tcb_context_create(TCB *thread, void (*start)(void*), void *arg) {
    makecontext( &(thread->context), (void (*) (void)) start, 1, arg);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of [`makecontext`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/makecontext.html) is `void`. Using `!` on a `void` is not correct.

In addition, you don't have a `return` statement outside the `if` block. Since the function's return type is `int`, you need to add a proper return statement. Otherwise, you will run into undefined behavior.

Comment: sorry forgot to copy the return 0 in the end, but the problem was with the if, i cant put it there, i dont know how i didnt see it, thanks!